# Can’t sign plugin using Grafana with Docker

Tags: docker, grafana, grafana-variable, grafana-api

I tried install this plugin to Grafana from github:

https://github.com/Vertamedia/chtable

I cloned this repository to pligins folder then added plugin to my grafana container:

```
grafana:
  image: grafana/grafana
  ports:
    - '3000:3000'
  environment:
    - GF_PATHS_CONFIG="grafana/etc/grafana.ini"
    - GF_PLUGINS_ALLOW_LOADING_UNSIGNED_PLUGINS=vertamedia-clickhouse-datasource,vertamedia-chtable
    - GF_INSTALL_PLUGINS=grafana-piechart-panel,grafana-worldmap-panel,vertamedia-clickhouse-datasource,vertamedia-chtable
```

Then when I tried create new dashboard panel using this plugin get error with message:

> An unexpected error happened TypeError: Cannot read property ‘emit’ of
> undefined

**Grafana version:** Grafana v7.4.3 (010f20c1c8)

My plugin is unsigned. How I can fix this error and use this plugin?

Comment: I recently faced the similar scenario with `grafana-zabbix` plugin. I ended up creating a grafana image from a custom `Dockerfile`

Comment: Can you show me your example `Dockerfile` if it is exists? I before don't created like this custom Grafana image. @SachithMuhandiram

Answer (score 3):

Here I will list steps I used to install `zabbix` plugin to grafana container. You may try following the similar way to this plugin.

First I downloaded `grafana-zabbix` plugin related files from offcial github.

`wget https://github.com/alexanderzobnin/grafana-zabbix/releases/download/v4.1.4/alexanderzobnin-zabbix-app-4.1.4.zip`

Extract that zip file.

Then in `gragana.ini` you have to uncomment `allow_loading_unsigned_plugins`. By default its commented.

To get this `grafana.ini` file, I ran `docker run grafana/grafana:latest` and connected to that running `grafana` container and copied `/etc/grafana/grafana.ini`

```
[plugins]
allow_loading_unsigned_plugins = true
```

Dockerfile

```
FROM grafana/grafana:latest

COPY grafana.ini /etc/grafana/grafana.ini

COPY alexanderzobnin-zabbix-app /var/lib/grafana/plugins/
```

Comment: Current grafana ini file path is really is `/etc/grafana/grafana.ini`?

Comment: @AndreasHunter as I remember it was.

Comment: Now I tried and path ini file was not changed. Thanks! @SachithMuhandiram

Comment: Now I tried uncomment and set `true` key of `allow_loading_unsigned_plugins` but plugins also unsigned. Also tried instead of `true` name of plugin.

Comment: Now I will install your plugin and let you know

Comment: Now I tried install `zabbix` plugin and disable `allow_loading_unsigned_plugins`. In this case this plugin without allowing signed.

Comment: @AndreasHunter actually you need to uncomment the line and make it look like `allow_loading_unsigned_plugins = true`

Comment: Can you also try install this plugin and sign? SachithMuhandiram

Comment: In `kubernetes-manifest` you just have to specify only your custom image only, no need to have ENV variables. Today I dont think I would get time. But I can try tomorrow.

Answer (score 0):

Using @SachithMuhandiram's answer I was able to get a **signed plugin** into running Grafana container. I do realize this doesn't answer the question asked (allow unsigned plugins). However, I did land on the thread while I was researching this problem. So, I'll leave the answer here, some may find it useful.

```
docker run -d -p 3000:3000 grafana/grafana
docker ps -a
docker cp relative/path-to/sample_plugin [container_id]:/var/lib/grafana/plugins/
docker restart [container_id]
```